# Prevent element from scrolling with page when position is fixed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to make an element have fixed position, but stop it from scrolling with the page?

My problem: I am building a tooltip that I dynamically determine the placement for depending on what space is available on the page for it. It needs to pop up over everything else next to its target element and not take up space. So I initially thought position absolute.

But absolute position is based off of the element's parent wrapper. My page gets wrapped in multiple various wrappers that I have no control over (on Salesforce, but this isn't necessarily a Salesforce specific question).

So I need to position it off of the viewport instead of relying on what parent it ends up getting wrapped in. So position fixed, works great.

The only issue is position fixed has the element scroll with the page. I don't really want the tooltip to follow the user as they scroll.

I feel I need to keep the position based on the viewport due to not being able to control the parent wrappers. But all I have found is position fixed, so not sure if some method exists to stop the element from scrolling with the page.

Comment: Remove the `postion:relative;` from the parents and add it to body.. That will help you to add tooltip on viewport.

Comment: I have no access to the parents it will get wrapped up in.

Comment: It would be great if you post some code for better understanding of your problem; If you can't then post gif image of what is happening right now (problem)..

Comment: There are multiple libraries out there like 'PopperJS' and 'Tippy' which implement this. Basically, they attach the tooltip to the body and depending on the target element that called it, they calculate the position. You can go through them too.

Comment: Well, `position:fixed` actually means it shouldn't scroll with the page (like the header on this page)... In any case, you could listen for the scroll event and hide the tooltip at that point. Not sure I've ever seen a tooltip that didn't close when the user scrolls.

Comment: Maybe that was worded incorrectly, but by 'scroll with the page' I meant that it followed the scroll (like the header does). Also, if this will require a third party library, then we won't be doing it. And there is no code to really post, and no gif... it is fairly straight forward. Tooltip appears, if user scrolls it follows, I don't want it to follow user scroll. The only relative code is my css, which is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to use `position: absolute;` instead of fixed.

Comment: Not necessarily due to the issue I outlined in the question. Position absolute means the tooltip will now be positioned based off of its parent (top, left css attributes will be based on parent origin). That doesn't really work for a tooltip because I need to know if it fits in the actual viewport, so I need positions based on the entire viewport.

Comment: @TylerDahle you can use position absolute, then analyze tooltip's position related to the viewport and if necessary - shift it with `margin`

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on `position: fixed`, the only way I know of to have the element move with the rest of the page as the user scrolls is by editing the location with JavaScript when the browser scroll event fires. Otherwise, if you position with respect to the viewport at first, you'll be positioned with respect to the viewport on an ongoing basis. However, hooking into the scroll event doesn't necessarily perform well, and although there are debouncer functions available to help with that, it wouldn't be my first choice.

You may be able to use `position: absolute` without tangling with the extra page wrappers, however. Is there is an element (call it A) that has these properties:

- your tooltip lives inside A (or can be moved there)
- you can correctly position your tooltip relative to A
- the extra wrappers are always outside A

If so, set `position: relative` on element A. Your tooltip will use A for reference and not an extra wrapper outside A (even if that wrapper also has `position: relative` set on it).